# Convention based Entity Framework Core returning the object associated with the foreign key when using Web API

Tags: ef-code-first, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.2

I'm using EF code first. By convention, I have added a foreign key and a reference to the foreign object (I believe this is needed). When I send a `Get` request to the API, it returns an `IEnumerable`. The problem is that each record returned also returns the complete object for the foreign key.

I've tried Googling the answer and for questions here on SO. I tried commenting out the reference to the other object but that didn't work.

```
public class Bill
{
    // other properties

    public Guid PersonId { get; set; }    // this is the foreign key
    public Person Person { get; set; }    // this is the reference to the foreign object
}
```

This is what is returned when executing the Get request:

```
[
   {
    //other fields
    "personId": "c28e52b0-1e40-46c4-812b-a61be7a69d53",
    "person": {
        //the entire other person object is returned here
       }
    },
]
```

How do I solve this without establishing a DTO for every model?

I'd like to hear if I'm using code first conventions improperly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET core 2.2 doesn't have return type `Json(Object)` as 2.1 did.

An ActionResult returning an anonymous type is one option, if you didn't want to use a DTO.

```
public IActionResult Get()
{
    return new OkObjectResult(new { PersonId = 99, OtherProperty = "more stuff" });
}
```

Response body:

```
{
  "personId": 99,
  "otherProperty": "more stuff"
}
```

Use ObjectResult if you need to return various status codes:

```
return new ObjectResult(new { PersonId = 99, OtherProperty = "more stuff"}) {StatusCode = 200};
```

Comment: So you are essentially building an object to send back? So, it sounds like a DTO might be the way to go if I want to reuse the object? I just upgraded to 2.2 from 2.1 and I'm still learning.

Comment: I certainly prefer to use DTOs, although like many things, you'll find lots of opinions out there. I use [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) most of the time for the conversions, does the trick and is simple to use.

Comment: I’ll check ou automappper. Thanks for the help!